# Clone from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I don't have any code on github account.
My code on the Heroku account. once I am cloning the code with "heroku git:clone -a myapp" command. everything comes up with clone but I see in db/migrate file, their is nothing in this folder means no migrations files are their.

How I can setup my application with all the fields. Application is working fine on Heroku.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes developers for various resons delete the databases migration and rely on the schema.rb file.  If you have a schema.rb file you can recreate the database using:

```
rake db:schema:load
```